# How to create a delegated event listener with my Jquery code

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, delegation

I am trying to make a delegated event listener so that when the user clicks one time the `p` tag is removed and an input box is appended. On a second click the input box is removed and and the p tag is appended.

Here is my code. Right now nothing works at all. Thank you!

```
    //User clicks p tag named "#hour1". 
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("document").on('click', "#hour1", function( event ){
        $("#hour1").remove();
        $("#hour1Data").append("<input id='hour1Input' type='text'/>");
    });
    });

//On Second click, input box is sent back to data box.
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("document").on("click", "#hour1Input", function( event ){
        $("#hour1Input").remove();
        $("#hour1Data").append("<p id='hour1'><?php echo $hour1; ?></p>");
    });
});
```

Comment: why not just show and hide rather than append and remove - would be much simpler, but as Quentin has said, your document shouldn't be wrapped in quotes.  Also you can put both your events into the same document ready

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a string containing a selector to jQuery and trying to bind the event handler to all `<document>` elements in the document. This fails because you don't have any (because HTML doesn't have any).

Pass the `document` object instead of the `"document"` selector.